# sending sms message in android that will open the web browser at the receiver. (in android)

Tags: android, sms, broadcast, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I want to send an sms message (either text or data), and that the receiver side will open the web browser according to the specific url i have sent him.

I need to clarify that I dont want the receiver side to have some kind of an app on his side, that listens to the broadcast of an incoming sms.
My intention is that an Intent of the web browser will be open according to my sent url, without an app that listens to it, and without the user presses the url shortcut, that he got in the text msg.

the idea is that the intent of the browser will be open automaticly as soon as I receive (or open) the sms msg.

If this is even possible, I will apriciate every answer that will lead me to the right direction.

thank you all.

Comment: In other words, want to send a spam _website_ instead of a spam _message_.

Answer (score 5):

Not possible. And I hope it never is.

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong spot for this question, but I'll answer it anyways...

Just send the full URL. Then a user can click on the link, and they can go to the website. I just tested this out, and it works.